# Proof about least prime numbers dividing n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Assume $n \in N$ is composite. Prove if p is the least prime number dividing
n, then   $p^2 \leq n$

Approach: I tried to write the first few prime and composite numbers but I didn't any patter. Any hints to start this problem

Comment: Hint:  if $p$ divides $n$ then $n=pm$.  Now  let $q$ be the least prime dividing $m$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: If $p$ is a prime number dividing $n$, then $n = kp$ for some integer $k$ (which is not 1 as $n$ is composite). What can you say about $k$ if $p^2 > n$?

Comment: Or rather, what can you say about the prime factors of $k$. Are they prime factors of $n$? Are they smaller than $p$?

Comment: by exahustion, I see that k is greater than p, but why does it make sense?

Comment: How do you get that? I don't understand

Comment: 10=5*2, so 2 is the least prime number and 5 is k

Comment: But we also assumed $p^2 > n$, remember.

Comment: If $q$ is a prime that divides $k$ (such a prime must exist), then $q$ also divides $n$. Can $q^2 > n$?

Comment: yes because if p>q then q would be the least element which is a contradiction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40697/discussion-between-theakholic-and-themathnoob).

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the least prime dividing $n$. Since n is a composite, $ \exists q \neq 1$ prime, such that $ q | \frac{n}{p} $. By assumption $ p \leq q $

$pq \leq n$ as $p$ and $q$ both divide $n$.

$ \implies pp \leq pq \leq n $

$ p^2 \leq n $

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, you can write 
$$
n=\prod_{j=1}^hp_j^{\alpha_j}
$$ 
where $p_1< p_2<\ldots< p_h$ and $\alpha_j$ are positive integers. By assumption, we have $p=p_1$. Moreover, because $n$ is composite, we know that either $h>1$ or $\alpha_1>1$. In the former case, $n\geq p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\geq p_1p_2>p_1^2=p^2$; in the latter case, $n\geq p_1^2=p^2$.